# JavaScript Chrome does not seem to support adding an id through setAttributeNode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, innerhtml

So I am working on a JavaScript searcher for my website, and It's been up for a few days, when I realized that it is not compatible with Chrome, so i checked a few other browsers and realized it works in Firefox and IE9, but does not work in Chrome or Safari.

I've been pouring over the debugger in Chrome and Firefox side by side for hours, and cannot for the life of me figure out what the problem is. It keeps giving me an error. I know exactly what the error means, and why it is giving me the error, but I cannot figure out what is causing it.

This is the error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

I know it means that there is no object with that Id, but I set an object to have that Id right before. In Firefox's debugger at that line of code it says that the Id has been set, but at the same line in Chrome's debugger it says it has not.

Here is an excerpt of the code:

```
  arrayFinal[arrayln2]="end";
  var displayNumber=0;
  while(arrayFinal[displayNumber].charAt(0) != "e"){
    var boxPath="camper_htmls/"+arrayFinal[displayNumber]+".txt";
    boxhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    boxhttp.open("GET",boxPath,false);
    boxhttp.send(null);
    var boxHTML = boxhttp.responseText;
    var setDivId=document.createAttribute("Id");
    setDivId.value=("div_"+displayNumber);
    var node = document.createElement("div");
    node.setAttributeNode(setDivId);
    document.getElementById("resultContainer").appendChild(node);
    var divIdNumber = ("div_"+displayNumber);
    document.getElementById(divIdNumber).innerHTML=boxHTML;
    displayNumber++;
  }
```

although a version of this code is being used on almost every page of the site, and none of them work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `id` instead of `Id` as in

```
var setDivId=document.createAttribute("id");
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/BuCrV/)

Comment: THANK YOU THANK YOU THANK YOU!!  it worked!  iv been trying to figure that out for hours.    do you know why chrome wont accept Id, when firefox will?

Comment: The answer was in the original question that got deleted. lol. You would have had the answer 3 hours ago if you paid attention.

Comment: Everyone was getting mad at me about not checking the debugger, and voting the question down, so I just deleted the question. Then went to youtube and learned how to use a debugger.  but it obviously didnt help.